# Why does Gatsby add __gatsby_resolved to some of my JSON files?

Tags: gatsby

I'm playing around with creating and editing JSON in a Gatsby site with TinaCMS. Whenever I edit a JSON file that has relationships to other JSON files, I get a __gatsby_resolved block added to my JSON file containing a handful of fields. These fields don't seem to correspond to my GraphQL criteria and I can't find any information on why / how they're being added.